# Data prep to import to Spark

Tags: data-import

We are working with 2 data sets:

1. export from Mailchimp as a csv,
2. export from Excel as a csv.
   I would like to start importing to CiviCRM Spark with clean data sets. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Mailchimp data imports pretty cleanly in my experience.  Excel data does not.

For the Excel data, I recommend first doing an *export* from CiviCRM.  You'll have the most success if you take the headers from the CiviCRM export and match your Excel data to those headers.  E.g. if you have a "name" column, CiviCRM has a "First Name" and "Last Name", so you'll want to split that up.

Comment: I'll give that a go - thanks.